# Apache Tomcat, StressTest WebApp

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat7, stress-testing

I´m in search of a tool who´s stress Testing a WebApp.

At the Moment I´m using several VM´s or (Privacy)Browser Windows to Test my Web Application under pressure.

Is there a better, smoother way to da this, e.g. any kind of Desktop Application, who generates a bunch of Traffic on my WebServer, an Apache Tomcat?

The server can be only accessed Local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make an accurate load testing if your server can only be accessed from the localhost. When starting a large number of threads that simulates your real users, the server machine will be slowed down by this thread management. Also on a single machine you can't simulate a very large number of users as it might be the case with a real/production server. For example you can't start 5000 threads on a single machine.

You need to make the server network visible and distribute your load generators across different machines. The load generator tools support such configurations.

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) for the load testing. They are good free tools.

Comment: Thx for your comment, I know i can´t meassure a stress Run on a single machine, have expressed myself wrong in this case ;) I meant how the App will state with more than one User, and for this JMeter is a good Tool. Tried this at the moment .

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html) is free. In many cases, much easier to use than other free alternatives.